# Reason my subroutine won't recurse

Tags: function, recursion, subroutine, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my %functiontable =();
$functiontable{foo} = \&foo;

sub iterate {
  my ($function, $iterations, $argument) = @_;
  return $argument unless 0 < $iterations;
  return $argument unless $function = $functiontable{$function};
  my @functioned = $function->($argument);
  my @refunctioned = ();
  for my $i (0 .. @functioned - 1) {
    push @refunctioned, iterate ($function, ($iterations - 1), $functioned[$i]);
  }
  return uniq @refunctioned;
}

sub foo {
  my ($argument) = @_;
  my @list = ($argument, $argument.'.', $argument.',');
  return @list;
}

my @results = iterate 'foo', 2, 'the';
print "@results";
```

This prints `the the. the,`, i.e. it doesn't iterate (recurse). I would expect it to print `the the. the, the.. the., the,. the,,`.

(I used Smart::Comments to check whether it enters `iterate` a second time, and it does, but it doesn't seem to do everything in the function.)

I can't figure out why. Can someone please help me figure out why, or propose a fix?

Comment: You modify the variable `$function` from a name to a subroutine reference, and then pass the reference to the iterate method.   You probably want to pass the name again.

Comment: @Miller, many thanks.

Comment: There are three answers, each of which is correct AFAICT and each of which touches more strongly on a point that the others gloss over ([Hunter McMillen's](/a/32058259) on using the ref as an argument directly, [Borodin's](/a/32058320) on what exactly caused my version to fail, and [Schwern's](/a/32058474) on smart variable usage). I don't know which to accept: all were very helpful.

Comment: @JQKP `perl -wle '@choices = qw(Schwern Borodin Hunter); print $choices[rand @choices]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time your subroutine `iterate` is called it translates the subroutine name in `$function` from a name to a subroutine reference

So the first time `iterate` calls itself it is passing the subroutine reference, and the line

```
return $argument unless $function = $functiontable{$function};
```

will stringify the reference and attempt to find an element of the hash using a key something like `CODE(0x23e0838)`

Clearly that element doesn't exist, so your `unless` fails and `$argument` is returned immediately without continuing the recursion

---

#### Update

I would write something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my %functions = ( foo => \&foo );

sub iterate {
    my ($func, $arg, $depth) = @_;
    return $arg unless $depth;
    map {iterate($func, $_, $depth - 1); } $functions{$func}->($arg);
}

sub foo {
    my ($arg) = @_;
    map "$arg$_", '', '.', ',';
}

my @results = iterate('foo', 'the', 2);
say "@results";
```

#### output

```
the the. the, the. the.. the., the, the,. the,,
```

Comment: Many thanks. (Note incidentally that this matches [Miller](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1733163/miller)'s earlier comment on the question.)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
return $argument unless $function = $functiontable{$function};
```

doesn't make sense. In your subroutine `iterate`, `$function` is a string and `$functiontable{$function}` is a reference to a subroutine. I am not sure what the purpose of this is: is it to compare against the stored function? is it to use the function referenced by the name `$function`?

Assuming the latter it would make more sense to simply pass in a reference to a function when you call iterate:

```
sub iterate {
  my ($function, $iterations, $argument) = @_;
  return $argument unless 0 < $iterations;

  my @functioned = $function->($argument);
  my @refunctioned = ();
  for my $i (0 .. @functioned - 1) {
    push @refunctioned, iterate ($function, ($iterations - 1), $functioned[$i]);
  }
  return uniq @refunctioned;
}

my @results = iterate($functiontable{foo}, 2, 'the');
print "@results";
```

output:

```
the the. the, the.. the., the,. the,,
```

Comment: Note `=` not `==`. I was assigning not comparing. But many thanks for the (rest of the) answer.

Comment: @JQKP ah my mistake, thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line.

```
return $argument unless $function = $functiontable{$function};
```

The variable `$function` is being repurposed and overwritten from a string (the function name) to a code reference (the function to be executed).  Later, it's passed into `iterate` which faithfully ignores it.

Two things would improve this code and avoid that sort of problem.  First is to not repurpose variables, use two variables.

```
return $argument unless $function_ref = $functiontable{$function_name};
```

Now the mistake cannot happen.  One strong indicator that you're repurposing a variable is that it changes type, like from a string to a code reference.

Note that I threw out `$function` entirely because it's too generic in this context.  Is that the function's name or the function's reference?  Neither one is obvious, so make it obvious.

Finally, `iterate` can be made more flexible by eliminating the function table entirely.  Pass in the code reference directly.  If you want a function table, write a wrapper.

```
sub select_iteration {
    my($iteration_type, $iterations, $argument) = @_;

    my $iteration_code = $iteration_types{$iteration_type};
    return iterate($iteration_code, $iterations, $argument);
}
```